# How can i get result(Pass/Fail) of all tests of a module in teardown_module() in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Here's my scenario.
I have one test_1.py file which goes like this

```
import pytest
def setup_module():
    print 'setup module'
def teardown_module():
    print 'teardown module'

class Test_ABC:
    def setup_class(cls):
        print 'setup class'
    def teardown_class(cls):
        print 'teardown class'
    def test_1(self):
        print 'test_1'
    def test_2(self):
        print 'test_2'
```

So here i would like to know if it is possible to get the result(Pass/Fail) of `test_1` and `test_2` tests.
Lets say, i need to send an email if any of the tests failed in the test suite.
And i am calling the email module in `teardown` module.

Comment: Asserts are the agreed upon form of determining pass/fail for a test rather than returns.

Comment: @DánielBencze I want the cummulative result of all tests in the module . How would i be able to do it by returning true or false ?

Answer (score 0):

in conftest.py under test package for example:

```
from _pytest.runner import runtestprotocol


def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):

    reports = runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
    for report in reports:
        if report.when == 'call':
            print('\n%s --- %s' % (item.name, report.outcome))

                if report.outcome is 'passed':
                    print('cool too')
                elif report.outcome is 'failed':
                    print('cool')
    return True
```

Another option will be:

```
    @pytest.fixture
    def after_test_report_pass_fail(request):
        yield
... your code goes here
```

then you can report on each item (test)